# T-SQL query calculating sum by product and scheme

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with following structure

```
id | productCode | schemeCode | balance
1  |2            | 1          | 200
2  |2            | 1          | 150
3  |2            | 2          | 70
4  |3            | 1          | 70
5  |3            | 2          | 100
6  |4            | 3          | 200
```

I need to write a query which fetch below result

```
ProductCode  |  schomeCode | Count |  Total
2            | 1           | 2     |350
2            | 2           | 1     | 70
3            | 1           | 1     | 70
3            | 2           | 1     | 100
4            | 3           | 1     | 200
```

Data is formatted on the basis of productCode and SchemeCode.

Comment: Simply `GROUP BY ProductCode, schemeCode`.

Comment: I did with productcode and schemecode but product and schemes are still repeated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select productCode, schemeCode, count(1) as [Count], sum(balance) as Total
  from table_name
  group by productCode, schemeCode
```